# Tensorboard training & evaluation metrics

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, object-detection-api

I'm training a Tensorflow Object Detection model and monitor progress in Tensorboard.

[image]

As you can see, it only shows training loss and evaluation precision. Is it possible to make it show evaluation loss and training precision too? How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Ended up updating TensorFlow to v1.14 and Models API to v1.13 (i was using v1.4). The new API has separate graphs for precision/recall and train/eval losses. This is enough in my case.

Comment: i dont see any of that .. using same  TensorFlow to v1.14 and Models API to v1.13  in colab??